# Best way to layout subviews on UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

Is there a good way to layout views from nibs onto a UIScrollView? Android uses LinearLayout so it automatically does this, but is there a similar way to do this in iOS? I want them to be centered on the scrollview horizontally, but they should stack on top of each other. Using

`[myScrollView addSubview:aView]`; obviously just puts them on top of eachother.

Comment: The most similar way with LinearLayout is to use auto layout.

Comment: Otherwise, you have set the offset of each view which will be added to the scrollView.

Comment: @trick14, I have set AutoLayout in my Storyboard, but how can I have this work programatically?

Comment: Here is a guide from Apple. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AutoLayoutinCode/AutoLayoutinCode.html

Answer (score 0):

I do not use any interface builders. I add subviews and init them with `CGRectZero`. I use `layoutSubviews` to set subviews' frames and scrollView's `contentSize`. And I never have problems with it. So, I suggest you to use `layoutSubviews`, `setNeedsLayout`, `viewWillLayoutSubviews`, `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` methods.

I don't know where do you want to change `scrollView` frame. If a scrollView is your custom view, try this in `layoutSubviews`:

```
CGRect newFrame = self.viewToBeCentered.frame;
newFrame.origin.x = (self.frame.size.width - self.viewToBeCentered.frame.size.width)/2;
self.viewToBeCentered.frame = newFrame;
```

If your scrollView is a subview of viewController.view, try this in `viewWillLayoutSubviews`:

```
CGRect newFrame = self.viewToBeCentered.frame;
newFrame.origin.x = (self.scrollView.frame.size.width - self.viewToBeCentered.frame.size.width)/2;
self.viewToBeCentered.frame = newFrame;
```

Comment: @Carpetfizz, yes, sure